# PHP nl2br() to new MYSQL row

Tags: php, mysql, nl2br

I have one text area where user can type in multiple lines. I would like to make it that when a new line is entered, it gets inserted as a new record in my table. How can I use the nl2br() function to accomplish this? Is there an easy solution I'm overlooking or do I need something other than nl2br?

Comment: You should split your string after each `\n` (newline) character and then insert each element separately. `nl2br` is not needed here, you may need it when displaying that data though.

Comment: nl2br() is a html formatting tool, rather than something to use for formatting for use in a database. I assume by table you mean database!

Comment: How do I detect each \n? Right now when I hit enter in the textarea and submit it into my database there is nothing to note the carriage return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nl2br() is only doing a replace of `"\n"` to `"<br>"` on whatever variable you pass.  It's not breaking the variable into multiple variables/array.

You would need to do something like

```
$lines = explode("\n", $_POST['text_area_input']);
foreach($lines as $line) {
    // do database insert query for each $line
}
```

Of course you should also be sanitizing the user input

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need but I guess my biggest problem is what I mentioned above in the comments. When I hit enter and type a new line it does not get stored with a "\n". Did I set up the texarea incorrectly or does that info just not get passed to a MYSQL table?

Comment: "\n" isn't a visible character per se.  If you are seeing a line break in the text it's either because of a "\n" or "\r" character.  Also on a related note, make sure you use double quotes with these characters in the PHP code, '\n' will evaluate to the literal "\" and "n" characters

Comment: When I type text in the text area and hit enter, then type on the new line it's interpreted as one block of text. I echoed out $line straight from the $_POST and there was no \n or \r. Just all the text as if it was one line. Do I need to do something to it to pick up on the break?

Comment: \n or \r are not visible characters.  The only way you "see" them is by the resulting new line that is created when the text is rendered. This may just add to the confusion, but the one thing I did forget to say, is it will most likely be "\r\n" for each new line.  This might help.  If you were to enter just, "1", "2", 3" each on their own line in the textarea, and then in your PHP script echo out strlen($_POST['whatever-field']); it's value should be 7

Comment: Got it! Perfect explanation. Thank you